# Making a C# library thread safe for WPF animations

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using the [Artefact Animator](https://github.com/goeran/ArtefactAnimator.Metro) library. This library is not thread-safe I've found.

Why does it need to be thread safe? My WPF application has [multiple UI threads](https://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/).

Is there a good trick to making this thread safe without re-coding the library? I've hacked it into submission by making multiple copies of the library and changing the library namespace for every thread I'm starting, but this is a poor solution because now I have multiple copies of my source code with tweaked using statements. Maybe there's some way to automate this or wrap the namespaces with reflection? I don't know.

For background on *why* I'm doing this: I have somewhere between 5 and 15k WPF image objects that I'm animating (on multiple monitors). The animations get choppy when they're all running on one thread. If someone has a better way to do this also, I'm open to solutions.

Comment: can't you create a thread safe wrapper for the Artefact Animator ?

Comment: I'd like to but the library makes extensive use of static variables, so I'm not sure how to

Comment: This might be incredibly difficult but would it be possible to run in separate app domains or processes and use IPC to communicate between if you need?

Comment: @alexw it would be possible, but probably significantly more difficult than my current hack

Comment: Hello! Have you found a solution for this? I have the exact same issue, been struggling with this for 3 days straight.

Comment: Also, I must add that the reason this is happening is because the library handles dependency objects created in the first thread it is used in and then those objects can;t be used in a different thread..

Comment: I never found a proper solution. I was using a maximum of 3 threads, so I kept 3 version of the assembly each with a different namespace; one for each thread. In the end I avoided the problem by generating a PNG sequence out of my animations, then played the PNG sequences instead of actually animating the 15k objects at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF requires that all windows/controls/dependency objects have thread affinity. So if you create a WPF window on a thread then all changes to that window must occur on the same thread in the future. As a result, virtually all WPF applications therefore have just a single user interface thread. Other threads might be used for background processing or other data processing activity but the feedback is then sent to the user interface thread for display.

I suspect your Artefact Animator library was written with this assumption in mind because that is how the majority of WPF apps are written. Converting the library requires you to understand its design and then correctly redesigning it to work as desired. This might be simple or near impossible depending on the library.